# How to call a comparator in a main class

Tags: java, comparator

I am wondering how to call a comparator from another class in order to use it in the main class. I created PacketComparator class, and would like to call the comparator in main method. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
public class PacketComparator implements Comparator<Packet> {
    public int compare(Packet p1, Packet p2) {
        if(p1==null || p2==null){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        int major1 = p1.getMajorPacketIndex();
        int major2 = p2.getMajorPacketIndex();
        int minor1 = p1.getMinorPacketIndex();
        int minor2 = p2.getMinorPacketIndex();

        // compare the two packets by using major index and minor index
        if(major1<major2){
            return -1;
        }else if(major1 == major2){
            if(minor1 == minor2){
                return 0;
            }else if(minor1 < minor2){
                return -1;
            }else{
                return 1;
            }
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

public class ImageDownloader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Packet[] array = PacketReceiver.receivePackets();

        PacketSorter.selectionSort(array, new PacketComparator);

        String imageOutputFilename = "finalImage.jpg";

        PacketRenderer.renderImage(array, imageOutputFilename);
    }
}
```

I am confused with how to call PacketComparator in the mainclass.

Comment: please post your source code

Comment: Please post what you have tried?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I did it now. Thanks.

Comment: Add your code as text in your question. Just add four spaces before every line it will be formatted as code. Images from these sites are deleted after a while then your question will be useless.

Comment: And for your code, you are missing the `()` `new PacketComparator()`;

Comment: The `compare` method of a `Comparator` is just like any method of any class, and is called in exactly the same way.  Is that what you're asking, or are you trying to get your **sort** to work?  If it's the latter, then just do as Jorge Campos suggests - add the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I just missed (), and I could fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line in your main class.

```
Collections.sort(array, new PacketComparator());
```

It will sort your code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It worked perfectly. And so I accepted your answer!  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the below lines in your main method.

Also I am not sure why you want to build something like this `PacketSorter.selectionSort` when you already have **Collections** API available.

```
PacketComparator comparator = new PacketComparator();
List list = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.sort(list,comparator);
```

Now your list is sorted

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I just missed (). And I could fix that.